# Accessing multiplexed I2C and UART pins of STM32F103 in arduino IDE

Tags: arduino-ide, i2c, uart

I want to access both of the multiplexed I2C and UART pins in the same program. I am programming in Arduino IDE.Can anyone please tell me how to access same pins for different functionalities?

Comment: I want to use Serial debug and MPU6050 in my application. All other pins are occupied with one or the other sensors and other devices. Only PB6 and PB7 is left., which is UART and I2C and I need both.

Comment: And how do you propose to remove the I2C device when using UART, and to remove the UART connection when using I2C?

Comment: If your chosen MCU doesn't have the resources that you need then you have chosen the wrong MCU.

Comment: do you have a network connection on the MCU? WiFi or Ethernet? use Telnet for debug output

Comment: No I dont have any network connection in the MCU

Comment: @Majenko Cant I do that in program? That is connecting both I2C and UART devices to the same pins and doing TDMA. like for some 100ms UART device will send information and for the next 100 ms I2C device will send data. When one device is sending data the other device will not be active.

Comment: this is the only one I2C device you use?

Comment: Yes. this is the only one

Answer (score 1):

In order to use two different peripherals on the same pins, you have to initialize I2C and de-intialize UART when using I2C and doing the opposite when using UART.

It’s **not** possible to initialize two different peripherlas on the same pins, concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. (Well, you can, but you mustn't).

I2C and UART are electrically incompatible bus systems.  UART is a Push-Pull system, whereas I2C is an Open-Drain system.  The Push-Pull connections will interfere with the Open-Drain outputs and I2C will not function.

If you want to have both you will need to include extra hardware (and the necessary control pins) to physically isolate the different devices from their respective bus when not in use.

Comment: Can I use a multiplexer to isolate the devices?

Comment: how do you want to control the multiplexer?

Comment: Only if it's a specialised multiplexer that knows about both UART and I2C. And I doubt such a thing exists.